# UV seams affecting normals

Tags: uv, normals

I have an issue with my UV seams. It looks like they affect the vertex normals as well and I don't know how to clean this.

UV split, correct unwrapping 
[image: Here is how it looks with the seam :]

UV welded, UV streched :'(
[image: And here is the result when welded:]

*EDIT* Here is a scene and some textures to support the question:

https://we.tl/t-AdHcLFR8vP

In this scene, there are two objects that are lit differently (the only difference is the UV unwrap) and I don't understand why. I mean, it appears the visible seam comes from the lighting not the textures

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it's not clear what's happening and you're trying to do, maybe show more screenshots, share your file, etc...

Comment: I created a simple scene, you can download it from here: 

https://we.tl/t-AdHcLFR8vP

There are two objects; the UV unwrap is the only difference; shading doen't look the same and I don't understand why :(

Comment: Maybe that's due to mirrored UV islands. Mirroring somehow screws up tangents and normals switch orientation. In your case select desired UV island and go UV->Mirror->Y or X

Comment: It looks like Serge has given the right answer, if you go in the UV Editor, select the face with the problem and press S X -1, it will flip the face and the problem will disappear

Comment: I see. Is there a way to select or show mirrored UV island then ? I see a selection for flipped islands but not mirrored :/